# Reporting based on different values in Dynamic Sender Profile

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have created a Dynamic Sender Profile to dynamically populate the from name and From Email for the email sends. There is a field as Network with 3 different types of values that would be used to populate 3 different From Name and from emails.
The client wants to report on these 3 values differently. Is there a way to run report like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be in Excel:

1)  Export the Data Extension with all your "Network" data out of Marketing Cloud and import into Excel

2)  Open the Job tracking, and click on the “Clicks” number.  This will allow you to export the subscribers out into Excel format.  Do this, and open up in Excel

3)  Perform a VLOOKUP function on the main Excel sheet (Step 1), looking at the “Clicks” Excel sheet to see whether each record has clicked or not

4)  Performed steps 2 – 3 for Opens, and any other metrics you would like to report on, such as Delivered

5)  Now create Pivot tables out of the data as required